# Select Effectiveness for every user

Tags: mysql

I have table storing every bet that user makes on a website. According to my question there are only 2 important columns:

```
+--------+--------+
| userid | status |
+--------+--------+
|      2 |      0 |
|      2 |      1 |
|      2 |      1 |
|      6 |      1 |
|      6 |      1 |
+--------+--------+
```

I want to calculate percentage of won bets for every user.
0 means lost.
1 means won.

So obviously percentage will be won bets/all bets.

I tried to do it by below query, but it doesn't work like it should be.

```
SELECT userid,(
(select count(id) as count_won from bets where status=1)
/
(select count(id) as count_all from bets where status!=-1)) * 100 as percent FROM bets group by userid;
```

I'm getting result:

```
+--------+---------+
| userid | percent |
+--------+---------+
|      2 | 80.0000 |
|      6 | 80.0000 |
+--------+---------+
```

It's counting all bets percentage. How i can make calculation for every user?

I know i can add WHERE clause with userid, but i don't want to do this, because after calculations i want to simply order results by percentage.

Does anyone can help me a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be helpful for you,

```
SELECT USERID
  , (COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN 1 END), 0) / COUNT(*)) * 100 STATUS1_PER
  , (COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 0 THEN 1 END), 0) / COUNT(*)) * 100 STATUS0_PER
FROM
MY_TABLE1
GROUP BY USERID;
```